# How to deploy a database to a windows azure sql database?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database that is sitting on on-prem sql server. I go to management studio and then select the database that I want to deploy on Azure and follow the guide. Eventually, I am getting a bunch of errors such as

> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
>   Error SQL71561: Error validating element [dbo].[patientInfo]: View: [dbo].[patientInfo] has an unresolved reference to object [198.18.21.71].[db_cs_dw].[dbo].[invoice]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.
>
> Error SQL71562: Error validating element [dbo].[getAllClaimsByPatientId]: Procedure: [dbo].[getAllClaimsByPatientId] has an unresolved reference to object [198.18.21.71].[db_cs_dw].[dbo].[all_clients_view]. External references are not supported when creating a package from this platform.

Do I need to set up a linked server on my Azure sql server with [198.18.21.71]. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

As others have rightly stated, you cannot set-up a linked server in Azure. The validation failures you're seeing are because 4-part [server].[database].[schema].[table] references have been detected, that aren't supported in Azure.

Assuming that your [db_cs_dw] database will also be hosted in Azure, you can perform an [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/) to perform the cross-database queries. There is a bit of set-up required to undertake this, including creating a security context, data source and [External Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935021.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396/) to represent the [invoice] table or any other data you wish to access in the other database. Your old references to  [198.18.21.71].[db_cs_dw].[dbo].[invoice] would now reference the External Table. You could also encapsulate this further by introducing [Synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) - so the synonym references the External Table and the [dbo].[patientInfo] view will reference the synonym.

Otherwise, you will need to host the data within the same database and have some kind of ETL/replication process in place to move/sync the data.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to set up a linked server on my Azure sql server with [198.18.21.71]. Can I do tHAT ?

you can't setup a linked server from Azure to onpremises..

as the error says,you need to resolve those conflicts by either removing the views or modfying them

Comment: How to modify them?

Comment: You can remove those views

Comment: I need those views and stored procedures .. is there a way to fix this error or go around it?

Comment: No.you can't.but one approach can be to materialize data from your view to an onpremise table and replicate it